# How do you encapsulate a MonoTouch.Dialog view into a view controller?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I am writing a view controller for adding a new item to my app. It is a perfect fit for MonoTouch.Dialog, as it can be done easily with a table based interface, with a field per relevant property of my item.

This is the code I have currently for showing the add item view (simplified, but the core idea remains):

```
Item item = new Item();
TapHandler handler = new TapHandler(); 
BindingContext bc = new BindingContext(handler, item, "Add Item");
DialogViewController dv = new DialogViewController(bc.Root, true);
this.NavigationController.PushViewController(dv, true);
```

While that works, I would prefer if I could encapsulate the details of the view into its own view controller, so the code could look like this:

```
UIViewController controller = new AddItemViewController();
this.NavigationController.PushViewController(controller, true);
```

However, I can't figure out how to implement this. I thought the logical thing to do would be to make a subclass of `DialogViewController`. However, all the constructors of `DialogViewController` require a `RootElement`. To get that, you need to firstly create the `BindingContext`. As you can't run any code before calling the base constructor, it doesn't end up working.

My second approach was to implement subclass of `UIViewController`, create the `DialogViewController`, and the add the dialog view controller as a child of my subclass using `this.AddChildViewController(dv)` and `this.View.AddSubView(dv.View)`. While this works initially, if you have the new view controller in a UINavigationController, and you click a date element, the date view appears as a modal popup rather than in the navigation controller hierarchy. (This makes sense, as the `DialogViewController` isn't part of the `NavigationController` hierarchy in this design).

From there I'm stuck. I couldn't find any examples of using MonoTouch.Dialog like this in the examples either. Is this possible to do? Or if it's not, is there a good reason as to why writing code like this is a bad idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way to do this, although it seems a little messy (thanks poupou for giving me the idea). I just set Root to null in the base constructor call, and then set it straight away in the contructor method:

```
class NewItemViewController : DialogViewController
{
    private Item _item;
    public NewItemViewController(bool pushing) : base(null, pushing)
    {
        _item = new Item();
        BindingContext bc = new BindingContext(this, _item, "Add Item");
        this.Root = bc.Root;
        // more setup
    }
    // more methods
}
```

I wasn't aware you could change the Root object, not just access it.

Answer (score 5):

> As you can't run any code before calling the base constructor

That's not quite correct.

It's not ideal but you can inherit from `DialogViewController` and provide it with an empty `RootElement` instance, like this:

```
public class AddItemViewController : DialogViewController {
    public AddItemViewController () : base (new RootElement ()) { }
}
```

Later you can add your things (or set a new `RootElement`) to the `Root` property, e.g.

```
void Populate ()
{
    this.Root.Add (new Section () { ... });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of manually using the Root element in the constructor. I made my own answer that works with the reflection api by setting a new Root element in the constructor.